# Javascript multiple OR in statement

Tags: javascript

I have a very basic statement that isnt outputting the correct value but I cant get my head around why.

My variable has the following value:

```
var bedroomNums = "0_1"
```

Yet this output displays as `true` in Chrome console:

```
bedroomNums != ("0_0" || "0_1" || "0_2")
```

I am trying to create an `IF` statement to say:

```
if bedroomNums doesnt equal X or Y or Z then the statement is true
```

I have tried:

```
bedroomNums != "0_0" || bedroomNums != "0_1" || bedroomNums != "0_2"
```

but this also displays true

Where am I going wrong

Comment: I think what you seem to be actually looking for is not a logical `OR`, but a logical `AND` (meets *every* condition).

Comment: `bedroomNums` cannot be three different values at the same time. If it equals "0_0", then by necessity it *won't* equal "0_1", so at least two of those ***or*** conditions must be true.

Comment: `bedroomNums != "0_0" && bedroomNums != "0_1" && bedroomNums != "0_2"`

Comment: Would this still work in parentheses `bedroomNum != ("0_0" && "0_1" && "0_2")`? IM not even sure if that is correct syntax

Comment: it's not the correct syntax for what you are seeking to do.  Each expression needs to compare `bedroomNum` (i.e.  `( bedroomNums != "0_0"  && bedroomNums != "0_1" && bedroomNums != "0_2")`

Comment: @AnthonyBroadbent What you've provided in your comment is technically valid ECMAScript syntax, but won't work the way you think it will. String values are "[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)", so `"0_0" && "0_1" && "0_2"` is actually `true && true && true`. Dependent on the type and value of `bedroomNums`, it's likely this comparison would *not* return the result you are expecting or need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're actually looking for is a [logical `AND`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND), which would ensure that *every* condition is met:

```
if (bedroomNums != "0_0" && bedroomNums != "0_1" && bedroomNums != "0_2") {
    // `bedroomNums` is not one of "0_0", "0_1", "0_2"
}
```

If one of these checks returns `FALSE` (that is, `bedroomNums` is set to one of these values), the code inside the curly braces will not be executed.

---

An alternative way to express this same condition would be to enumerate each of these values you're comparing against into an Array structure, then checking to ensure that the value of `bedroomNums` isn't present in said Array using [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if (!["0_0", "0_1", "0_2"].includes(bedroomNums)) {
    // `bedroomNums` is not one of "0_0", "0_1", "0_2"
}
```

This style is generally more helpful in situations where your program has to enumerate all possible values for a condition dynamically (based on some other logic or data source).